# Java member initialization in constructors

Tags: java

I'm taking my first steps into a new programming language after 4 years in c++, and I've chosen Java. I am trying to make a simple tick tack toe game using classes, but I'm having a hard time understanding the differences between java and c++.

in one java class file I have:

```
public class Game
{
    Player p1, p2;
    public Game(String p1Name, String p2Name)
    {
        System.out.println(p1Name + " vs. " + p2Name);
    }
}
```

---

In a separate java class file I have:

```
public class Player
{
    private String name;
    public Player(String name_in)
    {
        name = name_in;
    }
}
```

---

I want to know, how to initialize `Player p1, p2;` in the `Game` class, since I don't want to give the `Player` class a default constructor. I'm sure I could just overload the constructors, like this:

```
 public class Game
{
    Player p1, p2;
    public Game(String p1Name, String p2Name)
    {
        p1 = new Player(p1Name);
        p2 = new Player(p2Name);
        System.out.println(p1Name + " vs. " + p2Name);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Player
{
    private String name;
    public Player() { }       
    public Player(String name_in)
    {
        name = name_in;
    }
}
```

---

But, I'm wondering if there is a way to just initialize those objects without having to declare them and then initialize them. ie, just initialize them. If it were c++ I would just do this:

TL;DR: the code below is c++, how would I do a similar "one step member initialization" in Java.

```
class Game
{
    private:
    Player p1, p2;

    public:
    Game(std::string p1Name, std::string p2Name) : p1(p1Name), p2(p2Name) //<--One step member initialization
    {
        std::cout << p1Name << " vs. " << p2Name;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Player
{
    private:
    std::string name; 

    public:
    Player(String name_in) : name(name_in) { }  //<--Holy crap, another one.
}
```

---

Comment: Better: `public Game(Player player1, Player player2)`: inject your dependencies; let callers of the constructor work out how *they* want to construct the players.

Comment: Note: `name = name_in;` is more idiomatically written `this.name = name;`, where the parameter is called `name` too.

Comment: @AndyTurner - That's terrible advice. Variable shadowing is allowed by the language, but should be avoided to reduce confusion.

Comment: @AndyThomas terrrible advice, that's straight out of the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1): "Here, the constructor takes parameters having the same names as the fields to be initialized. This is simpler than having to invent different names for the parameters and is not too confusing in this stylized context. In general, however, it is considered poor style to have local variables with the same names as fields." Note that I wasn't advocating this in general, only for constructors (although, I don't see the harm in a simple setter either).

Comment: @AndyThomas I see variable shadowing all the time in production code. IMHO, variable shadowing simplifies and unifies naming rules.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Hmmm... I think that's interesting. So, having two different variables with the same name (what I'm assuming is called variable shadowing), won't cause any problems? It would help with having to come up with different variable names, which is extremely annoying to me.

Comment: @RhettPrestwich even in C++ it's quite common (therefore idiomatic) to use same variable names in constructors, e.g. `Player(String name) : name(name) { }` - here, the syntax of C++ initializers makes it unambiguously clear that the first name is the member and the second name is the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, there is no initializer like in C++, and there doesn't need to be one. Your original code was ok:

```
public class Game
{
    Player p1, p2;
    public Game(String p1Name, String p2Name)
    {
        p1 = new Player(p1Name);
        p2 = new Player(p2Name);
        System.out.println(p1Name + " vs. " + p2Name);
    }
}
```

From your question, you seem to be under the impression that with the above code you would need to add an (undesired) default constructor for class Player. Not so.

Remember that, unlike similar C++ declarations, the Java variables p1 and p2 are *references* to objects, not objects themselves. In the above code, p1 and p2 are first assigned to null and then, in the Game constructor, they are assigned to new objects. This may seem wasteful, but if it's run enough times the JIT will probably optimize away the unnecessary assignments to null, and just assign p1 and p2 directly to new objects.

Answer (score 4):

There is no one step member initialization in Java. Your best bet is to construct the `Player` objects in `Game`'s constructor,

```
public class Game
{
    Player p1, p2;
    public Game(String p1Name, String p2Name)
    {
        p1 = new Player(p1Name);
        p2 = new Player(p2Name);
        System.out.println(p1Name + " vs. " + p2Name);
    }
}
```

or to receive the `Player` objects in `Game`'s constructor.

```
public class Game
{
    Player p1, p2;
    public Game(Player p1, Player p2)
    {
        this.p1 = p1; 
        this.p2 = p2; 
    }
}
```